# Symfony 2 : Generated bundle will not find routes

Tags: php, symfony

I understand that symfony recommends to use the default AppBundle (as stated in this page http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/creating-the-project.html), however because my project is comprised of a number of stand-alone apps, I would like to separate them into their own bundles.

I am trying to generate a bundle with help of the symfony2 console generate:bundle command. Directory structures seem to be all in place, however I constantly get an error message that the route is not defined, although I have defined it.

The exception I get:

request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET /hello/somename"" at C:\wamp\www\symfony\test\app\cache\prod\classes.php line 2480 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException(code: 0): No route found for \"GET /hello/somename\" at C:\wamp\www\symfony\test\app\cache\prod\classes.php:2480, Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException(code: 0):  at C:\wamp\www\symfony\test\app\cache\prod\appProdUrlMatcher.php:35)"} []

Here is the setup:

routing.yml:

```
my:
    resource: "@MyBundle/Resources/config/routing.php"
    prefix:   /
app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
```

routing.php:

```
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Route;

$collection = new RouteCollection();

$collection->add('my_homepage', new Route('/hello/{name}', array(
    '_controller' => 'MyBundle:Default:index',
)));

return $collection;
```

MyBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php

```
namespace MyBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction($name)
    {
        return $this->render('MyBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array('name' => $name));
    }
}
```

The bundle is also properly registered in the AppKernel class.

As I understand it, calling mydomain.local/hello/somename should do the trick, but it won't work.

P.S. I Also tried the annotation method, but it wont work either (I get the same result)

P.S. 2 I know this is a much asked question, but non of the answers I have found so far seems to be helping me with the issue as is.

P.S. 3 the default AppBundle works properly, using similar settings (but annotations instead)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The debug message says that you are in prod environment.

Have you tried accessing your route from the dev environment : mydomain.local/app_dev.php/hello/somename or clearing the cache ?

Comment: Great. That worked. Did not think of clearing the cache (and honestly it did not fall into my attention that it is using prod environment. Just starting out with SF today...). Any quick tip on how to configure the correct environment? Thanks.

Comment: The basic environment configuration in the standard edition will fit almost all basic use cases. Most usually, I only create a custom test environment for unit and functional testing.